# Creating A Website Status Page

Tags: php, status

Is there anyway I can create a page on my website (PHP if possible) that would show the current status of my website and when it has/will have down time?

For example, could be similar to Google Apps Status Page at https://www.google.com/appsstatus

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create a PHP script which pings your app URLs from 2-3 different locations and then stores the result. The main page can then read the results. To be fast, you can cache the result for 3-5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to make a PHP script which loads one of your pages, looking for a specific content : if it finds it in a reasonable time, you can consider your site okay, if it doesn't find anything, or if your site takes too long to answer, you can tell you have a problem, and take action (for example, sending an email).

This script has to be launched regularly, so a cronjob has to execute it every x hours or so.

And, of course, it has to be on another hosting provider than your first website, because if there's an issue with the host, you can't tell it if your check script fails to load.

Edit : if this is complicated for you, some services can do it for free, like this one I found just now : https://uptimerobot.com/

Comment: that is kind of third party solution. what if we create a script in our website which keeps pinging or accessing a resource outside our hosting and keep logging per minute or per interval time defined. when we don't have logs we can guess the script didn't run or our site was down.

Comment: "a resource outside our hosting" seem pretty third-party to me.

Comment: yeah both ways. i am still rattling in my mind myself. But a legit question for sure

Comment: I edited my answer with a resource you may find useful.